# How to make a UIView animation similar to when App launches from Springboard

Tags: animation, uiview

I have a UIVew that I want to "pop" or "reveal" or whatever effect you see for Default.png when Springboard loads your App. Sorry if I'm not calling it the right name. Here is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
myView.alpha = 0.0f;
[myViewController.view addSubview:myView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
myView.alpha = 1.0f;
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

In any event, it doesn't give the desired effect. Instead, the view starts with a white background and gradually fades into the contents of the UIView. (Even this would be acceptable if I could make the background BLACK and perform the fade in.)

The ultimate desired effect would be a black background that makes it look exactly the way Springboard loads my Default.png.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

this example contains error:

```
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
```

myView.transform isn't similar to object that give `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)`. The sdk for iphone/ipod 3.1 throw this error.
Personaly, myView.transform must be `myView.view.transform`?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a tutorial showing how to make expanding views like in the facebook app, or when launching apps from the homescreen. Hope it helps:

[How to make expanding/shrinking views on iPhone SDK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dJJgUqCH0w&feature=PlayList&p=E97B882FB8C8C0D6&index=0&playnext=1)

Adam

Comment: Nice tutorial, but this is not quite the same effect as launching an app from the homescreen. If you look closely the source view is fading out and expanding _while_ the destination view is fading in and expanding. A subtle, but important, detail.